# Opening a WhatsApp chat from a website in IOS & Android

Tags: whatsapp

Is it possible to open a chat with a given phone number in WhatsApp from an website on IOS & Android? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a link like so?

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Check%20this%20out
```

The text parameter lets you pre-fill the chat box with some .. text : - )

As far as I know, you may also specify the recipient's number like so

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=4917241077
```

Just make sure you add the country code properly (49 would be Germany in this case)

Of course, you may combine parameters. I gave this a quick test yesterday since I need it for a project of mine and accessing this link on desktop opens the WhatsApp web chat. Doing so on a mobile phone opens the app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is not possible from within websites. Time to rest my case.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it is explained [here on their website](https://faq.whatsapp.com/563219570998715/?locale=en_US):

> Use [https://wa.me/{number}](https://wa.me/%7Bnumber%7D) where the {number} is a full phone number in international format. Omit any brackets, dashes, plus signs, and leading zeros when adding the phone number in international format.